# How to compile all py file to pyc file in a folder by writing a python script?

Tags: python

I work on win system, and I wonder a way that I can use a python script which could run in cmd lines to mass compile the py files.
I have write a simple python code.

```
import py_compile, os, glob
dir = 'D:\\FAS\\config'
for f in glob.glob(dir + '\\*.py'):
    py_compile.compile(f)
    print "Success compile the file:   %s" % f
```

It work inconveniently and can not compile the file in the folder's sub-folder. I hope your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
import compileall

compileall.compile_dir('D:/FAS/config', force=True)
```

Comment: Alternatively, from the command line: `python -m compilelall -f D:/FAS/config`

Answer (score 7):

***From the command line to compile all the files present in the current directory and in the subdirectory***, you can simply use the following command.

```
python3 -m compileall . -q
```

**remove -q if you want the list of compiled files.**

You can **stop recursion in subdirectories** by using -l in

```
python3 -m compileall . -l
```

You can write script for that as well.

```
import compileall

compileall.compile_dir('D:/FAS/config', force=True)
```

Force will rebuild even if timestamps are up-to-date.

[You can read more about it here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue when upgrading a library module. I had different module versions on different git branches and when I switch branch they stop working even if I recompiled using compileall.

My simple solution is to remove all `.pyc` files from the library and run the scripts so that it compiles all necessary modules itself. It worked!!

Easy command to remove the pyc files `find libs/ -name *.pyc -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Instead of dealing with `find`'s horrid interface and worrying about escaping shell characters, I just used `find -name '*.py[co]' -delete` in a `Makefile`.